# Run a command only after rsync has altered something?

Tags: rsync, updates

I want to run a command (service restart) only after a rsync cronjob has altered said service's files.

Is this possible? Like a rsync flag or exit code?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a way you can achieve this is comparing the `md5sum` hash of the directory that contains the newer files you'll use `rsync` on, compare it with the `md5sum` of the files in the destination directory and if one of them differs you already know you need to restart the service.

A way to get the `md5sum` is running the command with the same name:

```
$ md5sum keyring 
66f581b36c1401859442e2a34c7596eb  keyring
```

If 2 files are equal, they'll have the same `md5sum`.

Also, if the origin directory has a file that is not in destination yet, you'll also need to restart the service.